# Changing image to another on click

Tags: javascript, php, image, click

We are currently creating an image inside a holder (ch-item) as shown below:

```
<div class="ch-item ch-img-1" style="background: url(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/image1.jpg);">
```

If possible we would like to make this image change to another when clicked, and repeat this process six times in all, so each time it is clicked it changes to another image.

We would greatly appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: If you don't want the page to reload after each click, you need to use JavaScript, not PHP.

Comment: Welcome to SO. As @Jessica mentions, the type of function you're looking for is Client Side scripting, JavaScript, and not server side scripting, done by PHP. Please post what code you have tried in JS so that we can help with that.

Comment: or mix of both, server and client but this is another story ;)

Comment: Thanks for the help. The PHP we've used isn't necessary. If we were to solely use Javascript, what would you recommend? I apologise for being a massive noob.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it using solely Javascript:

```
// Counter to keep track of which the current image is
var counter = 0;

// List of images
var images = [
    'http://cdn.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Seemly-l.jpg',
    'http://cdn.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Handsome-l.jpg',
    // Add more images here
];

window.onload = function () {
    // Get the container div
    var gallery = document.getElementById('gallery');

    // Run updateImage function on click
    gallery.addEventListener('click', updateImage);

    // Run updateImage on start
    updateImage();    
}

function updateImage() {
    // Get the container div
    var gallery = document.getElementById('gallery');

    // Set background image    
    gallery.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[counter] + ')';

    // Update counter
    counter++;

    // Remove old class name
    if (counter == 1) { // Remove last
        gallery.className = gallery.className.replace(
            ' ch-img-' + images.length,
            ''
        );
    } else { // Remove previous
        gallery.className = gallery.className.replace(
            ' ch-img-' + (counter - 1),
            ''
        );
    }

    // Add new class name
    gallery.className = gallery.className + ' ch-img-' + (counter);

    // Reset counter when at the end of the images list
    if (counter == images.length) {
        counter = 0;
    }
}
```

And here is a JSFiddle to try it out:

https://jsfiddle.net/0tg6up0o/14/